# I want to send OTP in Mail and also want to save the generated OTP in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email

I am creating a Login proj which require otp to login successfully. So I have created the frontend part in angular and backend in Springboot.
I have made EmailService class and OtpMailController class but cant figure what to do next.
Also created column in tables.
I need to generate random otp and then send it to the user mail address. Login & Registration part has been done.

Here is my code :

Entity :

```
public class SessionHandling {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String cpassword;
    
    private static final long OTP_VALID_DURATION = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // 5 minutes
    
    @Column(name = "one_time_password")
    private String oneTimePassword;
     
    @Column(name = "otp_requested_time")
    private Date otpRequestedTime;



    public boolean isOTPRequired() {
        if (this.getOneTimePassword() == null) {
            return false;
        }
         
        long currentTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long otpRequestedTimeInMillis = this.otpRequestedTime.getTime();
         
        if (otpRequestedTimeInMillis + OTP_VALID_DURATION < currentTimeInMillis) {
            // OTP expires
            return false;
        }
         
        return true;
    }
    
    
    
    public SessionHandling(int id, String name, String email, String password, String cpassword) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.cpassword = cpassword;
    } // all getter and setter
```

EmailSenderService :

```
@Service
public class EmailSenderService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    
    public void sendMail(String toEmail,
                         String subject,
                         String body) {
        SimpleMailMessage message=new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("mygmail@gamil.com");
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setText(body);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        
        mailSender.send(message);
        
        
    }
    
}
```

OtpMailController :

```
@Controller
public class OtpEmailController {
    
    private EmailSenderService emailService;

    Random random = new Random(1000);
    
    @PostMapping("/send-otp")
    public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        
        int otp = random.nextInt(999999);
        
        String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
        String toEmail = email;
        String body = "<h1> OTP = " + otp + "</h1>";
        
          this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
          return ("success");
    }
```

application.properties file :

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=mygmail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=mypassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```